# How can I trigger my repo's deployment based on a third party repo I don't control?

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, github-actions, circleci

How can I trigger my repo's deployment based on a third party repo I don't control?

I have my project, which is dependant on some repository I don't control (a repository full of publicly available data). I want to make sure that every time this data-repo is updated my CI triggers a rebuild.

How can I set this up?

Can be either CircleCI or GitHub Actions.

Comment: With GitHub Actions, one possible solution could be to watch the repo (i.e. polling) for any new updates by using the [`schedule`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#schedule) event and then proceed with deployments accordingly if there are any.

Comment: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/22956 seems to agree with @Azeem

Comment: I know there is a RSS feed for each repo, that is public. https://github.com/<org>/<repo>/commits/<branch>.atom. Could that be used for something? ;)

Comment: @TomaszGałkowski: Yes, looks like you can utilize the RSS feed to check for new updates against a specific branch.

Comment: I'm not sure if that would work, but what if you add that other repository as a submodule of your own repository?